# Delaware registration service

Tags: business

Is a corporate registration service located in Delaware compelled to reveal the identity of one of its customers upon my request?

I am trying to track down *anybody* from a particular company that is registered in Delaware under the name of a corporate registration service. I have had no luck by any other means, so I've considered calling the service and just asking. Can I expect success?

Answer (score 1):

The *most* they can possibly give you are forwarding addresses and contact information for an entity they represent.

One of the functions of a corporation is to shield the identity of owners.  If an owner specifically does *not* want to be found then you're not going to find that person through its registered agent.

However, there's no law against asking.  At the very least you could ask the registered agent to forward a message asking that you be contacted.  Though, AFAIK, they can't be *required* to forward anything but legal notices.

Answer (score 1):

No private party is going to be ***compelled*** to do anything upon a simple ***request*** by another private party unless they agreed to do that thing in advance. Since they have no relationship with you, that's unlikely.

***Will*** they? Probably not. But like you said, it's worth a shot.

If you want to compel them, you might need to serve them with a ***subpoena*** pursuant to a law suit.